# Winforms DataGridView databind to complex type / nested property

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, .net-3.5

I am trying to databind a `DataGridView` to a list that contains a class with the following structure:

```
MyClass.SubClass.Property
```

When I step through the code, the `SubClass` is never requested.

I don't get any errors, just don't see any data.

Note that I can databind in an edit form with the same hierarchy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_knowledge).

Create a property on MyClass that exposes the SubClass.Property. Like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private SubClass _mySubClass;

   public MyClass(SubClass subClass)
   {
      _mySubClass = subClass;
   }

   public PropertyType Property
   {
      get { return _subClass.Property;}
   }   
}
```

Comment: right, that was my last case scenario, but I have 7 subtypes do deal with so I was looking for a better way. Thx for the tip though.

Comment: @BZ http://www.developer-corner.com/blog/2007/07/19/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/

Answer (score 5):

You can add a handler to DataBindingComplete event and fill the nested types there.
Something like this:

in form_load:

```
dataGridView.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView_DataBindingComplete);
```

later in the code:

```
void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
        DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        string consumerName = null;
        consumerName = ((Operations.Anomaly)row.DataBoundItem).Consumer.Name;
        row.Cells["Name"].Value = consumerName;
    }
}
```

It isn't nice but works.

Comment: It could be faster than casting all of your items to a subtype before databind.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind a DataGridView to nested properties. It's not allowed.

One solution is to use this [ObjectBindingSource](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ObjectBindingSource.aspx) as a Datasource.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq too!

Get your generic list and use .select for choose the fields like the exemple below:

```
 var list = (your generic list).Select(i => new { i.idnfe, i.ide.cnf }).ToArray(); 

 if (list .Length > 0) {
      grid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      grid1.ColumnCount = 2;

      grid1.Columns[0].Name = "Id";
      grid1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "idnfe";
      grid1.Columns[1].Name = "NumNfe";
      grid1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "cnf";

      grid1.DataSource = lista;
      grid1.Refresh();

}
```