# Databinding in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a model (class) called motor which consist of another two models (spec model, description model) as its properties. In either spec or description model, there are a few properties as well.

I want to bind a list of motors to a datagridview. Unfortunately, it seems that the datagridview can not detect the properties of spec and description models. Maybe too many layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off autogenerate columns, and create the columns and bindings yourself:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MotorCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SpecModel.Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DescriptionModel.Name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

UPDATE:

I didn't realize this was about winforms. In that case I don't think you can bind to nested properties directly, but as suggested here: [Winforms DataGridView databind to complex type / nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683796/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-complex-type-nested-property) you can make a property on the top model accessing the nested properties.

Otherwise it seems as if you can create your own typedescriptor as suggested here [How to bind a DataGridView column to a second-level property of a data source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx), but that's maybe a little out of scope if you are just dealing with a simple model.

Comment: So, the "SpecModel" is my class name or the property name inside motor model?

Comment: It's the property name. And the .Name is just an assumed property name on the SpecModel class. Basically you can always bind to nested properties like this Property.Property.Property etc.

Comment: No, I tried, but didn't see any changes reflected in the datagridview.

Comment: Ok, try and post some sample code, and I will try and give a more concrete answer.

Comment: motorListBinding.DataSource = mainController.GetMotorList();
 dgvMotorList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 dgvMotorList.DataSource = motorListBinding;tranplier;