# Bind ViewModel sub-properties to DataGridView column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel with a Model property:

```
public AnimalViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
  private Animal model;
  public Animal Model
  {
    get { return model; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref model, value); }
  }

  private String rowError;
  public String RowError
  {
    get { return rowError; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref rowError, value); }
  }

  public ViewModel( Animal _model )
  {
    Model = _model;
  }
}
```

Then I have a ViewModel collection:

```
public AnimalsViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
  private ReactiveList<Animal> animals;
  public ReactiveList<Animal> Animals
  {
    get { return animals; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref animals, value); }
  }

  private IReactiveDerivedList<AnimalViewModel> animalViewModels;
  public IReactiveDerivedList<AnimalViewModel> AnimalViewModels
  {
    get { return animalViewModels; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref animalViewModels, value); }
  }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    Animals = new ReactiveList<Animal>();
    AnimalViewModels = Animals.CreateDerivedCollection( x => new AnimalViewModel(x) );
    Model = _model;
  }
}
```

In Winforms, I want to bind `DataGridView.DataSource` to `AnimalViewModels`. This will let me take advantage of the `RowError` property. However, the fields for the contents of the grid are now under the sub property `Model`.

In the designer, I set `DataPropertyName` for a column to `Model.SomeAnimalField`. Although the code runs, the `DataGridView` cells are blank. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Essentially, this is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683796/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-complex-type-nested-property. I assume there is no ReactiveUI solution to this problem?

Comment: [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35117378/3110834)